# Page with iframe inactivity redirection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, redirect, iframe

I have a page with an iframe in it. I put on a code where the page will redirect to the home page if user is inactive for x number of seconds(absence of keydown and mousemove). My problem is the code only works in the mother page but does not detect the mousemove and keydown in the iframe, thus making it redirect everytime inside the iframe despite activity. I tried calling a function in the onload event of the iframe but this doesn't ssem to work. Here is the code for the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>SAMPLE</title>
<link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script language="javascript">
function redirect()
{
var timer;
window.onload= document.onmousemove= document.onkeypress= function(){
clearTimeout(timer);
timer=setTimeout(function(){location= 'index.html'},3000);
}
}
</script>


</head>

<body bgcolor="blue" onLoad="redirect();">
<iframe src="http://tplink.teleperformanceusa.com" frameBorder="0" width="100%" height="800px" onLoad="redirect();"></iframe>

...

</body>
</html>
```

any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Don't use iFrames, they're outdated.

Comment: In what way can I possibly display a page that I have no control of?

Comment: @Jonast92 If iframes are outdated, what should be used instead?

Comment: or, is there any way that i can embed my dock to a redirecting site if I have no control over it?

Comment: why shouldn't you try for the php session for this case?

Answer (score 1):

You have your iframe set to 100% width and 800px height. That is almost all of your webpage. 
Iframes were designed to insert responsive sections of other webpages into a page. In your code it looks like the whole of the page is the iframe. So you have to ask yourself, why do you need the iframe if it is almost all the page? Why not just link to the page?

Basically the 'motherpage' will not detect movement and activity in the iframe becuase it is outside of its control, and therefore will action the script you have written. The only activity taking place is on the webpage you are linking to in the iframe. 
Try to avoid iframes.

Comment: I need my dock still present in the linking page, but I have no control over the page in the iframe. Thanks for the help anyway! Not able to vote up yet but you are a help! Thanks!